# 2004 Mustang 40th edition won't start sometimes

Tags: battery, starting

I just replaced the battery for Mustang 2004 and after a month I started having problem.

When I start the car it won't start and there is no noise and no light on. But after I I take the battery cables out and put them back on it starts normally and that happens like once every 5 days approximately.

Comment: So you're saying nothing is coming on?  Do you have anything aftermarket installed?  To be clear are you saying this happens when the vehicle sits or you regularly use the vehicle and the issue occurs about every 5 days?  Did this do this before the battery replacement?

Comment: Nothing coming on . I use it almost everyday for a short drive .and yeah I have replaced the battery just about. A month ago because battery died and Ii didn't have that issue with old battery